# how to resolve WSAEWOULDBLOCK error

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I have an win7 application where i am sending data b\w 2 clients on a TCP connection. While testing i found out that i was getting `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error frequently on my socket. To 
resolve this error i put a while loop around it for ex.

```
do  
{  
size_t value = ::send();  /*with proper arguments*/
}while(GetLastError() == 10035);
```

So if i get `error 10035` i will resend the data.

But now i see that this while loop runs sometimes infinitely and my application goes
into kind of deadlock state. I tried increasing the size of socket but still of no use.

If anybody has any idea how to resolve `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error please let me know.

Comment: `size_t value = socket();` what is it? Do you get `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` during socket *creation*? If not, do you use non-blocking mode (if you do, why?)?

Comment: You don't need infinite loop. Instead you can want for socket event and when the socket is ready for send, you are to be notified.

Comment: did you mean `send()` instead of `socket()`? (with proper parameters)

Comment: Why are you using non-blocking mode when you don't know how? I would just use blocking mode, unless you know you need non-blocking, in which case you should certainly learn how to use select().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WSAEWOULDBLOCK is not really an error but simply tells you that your send buffers are full. This can happen if you saturate the network or if the other side simply doesn't acknowledge the received data. Take a look at the select() function, which allows you to wait until buffer space is available or a timeout occurs. There is also a way to bind a win32 event to a stream, which then allows its use with WaitForMultipleObjects in case you want to abort waiting early.

BTW: I initially wanted to object against your use of the term "deadlock", but this is also something that could be happening: If you wait to send some some response before receiving the next request, and the other side wants to send a next request instead of receiving your response, your applications are effectively deadlocked. Using select(), you can determine whether you can send data, receive data or that the connection has failed, which allows you to handle these case correctly and when they occur.

Note: I also assume that your code is not really a call to socket() but one to send/recv.

Comment: It also happens if the peer doesn't read as fast as you are writing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just used select before sending the data on socket and it works fine for me know.